# Run function with elevated privilege

Tags: ssl, rust, process, ssl-certificate, root

I would like to start my rust app as regular user, i.e ./myapp.
When user will enable some feature, I would like to run fn, as root ( I would like to add a self signed certificate to system certificate store).
My goal is to avoid as possible to start my app as root

I think I need to start a child process right ?
And I have to use nix crate too ? To set uid to 0 ?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you error out on insufficient privileges and require the user to do it themselves, with sudo or other platform specific utilities? @bk2204 hints at this approach

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not possible to gain privileges in the same process without the help of some outside tool.  That's useful from a security point of view, since it means that once a process has permanently dropped privileges, it doesn't have to worry about the possibility of an exploit causing it to regain privileges.

The usual way to do this is to implement some sort of setuid-root helper process.  That process, which may only be executable by a special group or which may perform special checks to restrict access, can then perform the privileged operation of installing the certificate.  This necessitates a separate binary, however.

You can also start your app as root or as setuid-root, but then immediately drop privileges with `seteuid` and `setegid` to an unprivileged user, regaining the privileges (again with `seteuid` and `setegid`) to perform the privileged operation, and finally dropping them permanently with `setuid` and `setgid`, plus `setgroups`.  Note, however, that this is much less recommended because it makes any exploit in your program before it has permanently dropped privileges exploitable as root, which you probably want to avoid.

Except for those two options, there really isn't any way to gain privileges.  Note that the use of sudo is essentially the first case: a privileged helper.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (with the `libc` crate) of temporary, then definitive, privilege revocation.

The idea is to start with some privileges (thanks to the setuid bit) and revoke it as soon as possible in order to limit risks, then get them back for a specific operation where they are needed, and drop them again afterwards.

The property of the process, which is considered for the privileges, is the *effective* uid.
When the setuid bit is set on an executable (`chmod u+s`), the *effective* uid of the process running this executable is the owner of the file (`chown 0`), not the caller (which is kept in the *real* uid).
Replacing the *effective* uid with the *real* uid drops these privileges.
In theory this should be one way, but thanks to the *saved* uid (which is a copy of the initial *effective* uid), we are allowed to reassign the *effective* uid to its initial value (0 here).

Note that this is not a safe situation because some malicious code could also regain the initial privileges.

For the revocation to be definitive, we need to make the process forget its *saved* uid.
After that, we cannot obtain the initial privileges back, and neither can a malicious code.

```rust
fn getresuid() -> (libc::uid_t, libc::uid_t, libc::uid_t) {
    let mut ruid = 0_u32;
    let mut euid = 0_u32;
    let mut suid = 0_u32;
    unsafe {
        libc::getresuid(
            &mut ruid as *mut _,
            &mut euid as *mut _,
            &mut suid as *mut _,
        )
    };
    (ruid, euid, suid)
}

fn show_uids() -> String {
    let (ruid, euid, suid) = getresuid();
    format!("real={} effective={} saved={}", ruid, euid, suid)
}

fn write_file(
    path: &str,
    content: &str,
) {
    match std::fs::write(path, content) {
        Ok(()) => println!("{:?} written", path),
        Err(e) => println!("cannot write to {:?}: {:?}", path, e),
    }
}

fn temporarily_revoke_privileges() {
    let (ruid, _euid, _suid) = getresuid();
    unsafe { libc::seteuid(ruid) };
}

fn restore_privileges() {
    unsafe { libc::seteuid(0) };
}

fn definitely_revoke_privileges() {
    let (ruid, _euid, _suid) = getresuid();
    unsafe { libc::setresuid(ruid, ruid, ruid) };
}

fn main() {
    let top_file = "/top_file.txt";
    //
    println!("~~~~");
    println!("at startup: {}", show_uids());
    write_file(top_file, "at startup");
    //
    println!("~~~~ temporarily drop privileges as soon as possible ~~~~");
    temporarily_revoke_privileges();
    println!("after revocation: {}", show_uids());
    write_file(top_file, "after revocation");
    //
    println!("~~~~ get privileges back for a specific operation ~~~");
    restore_privileges();
    println!("after restoration: {}", show_uids());
    write_file(top_file, "after restoration");
    //
    println!("~~~~ definitively drop privileges when done ~~~~");
    definitely_revoke_privileges();
    println!("after definitive revocation: {}", show_uids());
    write_file(top_file, "after definitive revocation");
    //
    println!("~~~~ restoration attempts won't work anymore ~~~~");
    restore_privileges();
    println!("after restoration attempt: {}", show_uids());
    write_file(top_file, "after restoration attempt");
}
/*
$ cargo build
$ sudo chown 0 ./target/debug/my_project
$ sudo chmod u+s ./target/debug/my_project
$ ./target/debug/my_project
~~~~
at startup: real=9223 effective=0 saved=0
"/top_file.txt" written
~~~~ temporarily drop privileges as soon as possible ~~~~
after revocation: real=9223 effective=9223 saved=0
cannot write to "/top_file.txt": Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" }
~~~~ get privileges back for a specific operation ~~~
after restoration: real=9223 effective=0 saved=0
"/top_file.txt" written
~~~~ definitively drop privileges when done ~~~~
after definitive revocation: real=9223 effective=9223 saved=9223
cannot write to "/top_file.txt": Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" }
~~~~ restoration attempts won't work anymore ~~~~
after restoration attempt: real=9223 effective=9223 saved=9223
cannot write to "/top_file.txt": Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" }
*/
```